# Casting generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Can someone help me with a work-around for this issue?

I have the following class:

```
public partial class FObjectSet<T> : IObjectSet<T> where T : class
{
...
}
```

I also have the following class:

```
public partial class FContext : IContext, IDisposable
{
    public ObjectSet<T> CreateObjectSet<T>() where T : class
    {
        var fakeObjectSet = new FObjectSet<T>();
        return (fakeObjectSet as IObjectSet<T>) as ObjectSet<T>;
    }
}
```

The `CreateOjectSet` method returns a null as the cast is not working.

p.s. The code above is trying to fake the `System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet` method.

Comment: Does `FObjectSet<T>` inherit from `ObjectSet<T>`? If not, it won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, FObjectSet does not appear to inherit from ObjectSet. It only implements the IObjectSet interface.

If it did inherit from ObjectSet, you wouldn't need to cast it to a IObjectSet before casting it to an ObjectSet, in fact, you wouldn't need to cast it at all...

```
public partial class FObjectSet<T> : ObjectSet<T> where T : class
{
...
}

public partial class FContext : IContext, IDisposable
{
    public ObjectSet<T> CreateObjectSet<T>() where T : class
    {
        var fakeObjectSet = new FObjectSet<T>();
        return fakeObjectSet;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because `FObjectSet<T>` doesn't extend `ObjectSet<T>`.  You could return `IObjectSet<T>` instead, but I don't know if that would do what you want.